# SVG with <a> tag does not work

Tags: craft3, svg

I want to put some links on an image. To be exact, this "Click here" would be a link. I supposed it would be possible with SVG image.

[image]

However,  tag does not work in web page powered by Craft CMS. How can I make it available?
If not possible, is there any alternative? I already found image map does not work in Craft.

Probably the cause is Craft CMS's specification, because if I open the image with a new tab, the links work without any trouble.

The part of the text with a link is this;

```
<text x="927" y="584" class="cls-2">
    <tspan x="927" dy="1.2em"><a xlink:href="https://stackoverflow.com/" class="cls-link" target="_blank">Click here</a> for more information.</tspan>
</text>
```

My Craft version is 3.5.12.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you placing the SVG into your web page within an IMG tag, by any chance? If so, try changing to an inline SVG instead. There are quite a few SVG features that don’t work unless you use inline SVG, and from memory links are one of them.

Comment: Yes, inline SVG works, thank you. However, the source code is automatically sanitized, so it is necessary to be wrapped by <figure>.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, the config setting `sanitizeSvgUploads` could be of help.

> Whether Craft should sanitize uploaded SVG files and strip out
> potential malicious-looking content.

https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/config-settings.html#sanitizesvguploads

Comment: Thank you, I tried, but unfortunately the link still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to summarize the conclusion.

In order to embed link on SVG image in Craft CMS website, inline SVG is the solution. It works with putting a source code into rich text field, like this;

```
<figure style="width: 100%;"><object data="{{ image_url }}" type="image/svg+xml" width="100%"></object></figure>
```

In addition, there are some tips;

- The `<object>` should be wrapped by `<figure>`, otherwise Craft
  sanitizes the code automatically.
- Width of `<figure>` is necessary to display the image with proper size in Chrome and Edge.